# Prompt user to select a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro, that prompts a user to select an Excel file, like this:

```
Dim thisBook As Workbook, newBook As Workbook
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim oFD As Variant
Dim fileName As String

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xls", 1
        .Title = "Choose the Report"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        .Show
        For Each oFD In .SelectedItems
            fileName = oFD
        Next oFD
        On Error GoTo 0
 End With

 If fd.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then

     Exit Sub

 End If

 Set thisBook = ActiveWorkbook
 Set newBook = Workbooks.Open(fileName)
```

This works fine, what I want to do now, and what I failed to find in the internet is the following:

I want to prompt the user to select a worksheet from the `newbook`, since the sheet name could not be the same in the future.

I came up with this, but I am not very happy with it, since it is rather inconvenient, to let the user type the sheet name:

```
Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function q() As String
Dim shname As String
Do Until WorksheetExists(shname)
shname = InputBox("Enter sheet name")
If Not WorksheetExists(shname) Then MsgBox shname & " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation
Loop
q = shname
End Sub
```

Is there a way, to maybe let the user select the sheet name, from all the sheet names? (I am not using an Userform, the Macro starts, if the user clicks a Button)

Comment: Why not make a userform with a combobox control? Populate the combo box's  with valid sheet names. Even if your macro is launched by a button, your macro can invoke userforms.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this, but I don't know how to do this. I would have to make the Userform by hand first, then launch the Userform from within my Macro and populate the combo box, let the user select the sheet name and return this name. Does the code pause while the userform is loaded? How do I return a value from a combo box to a macro?

Comment: You should be able to find some good tutorials about userforms and combo boxes (this looks promising: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/populate-a-userform-combo-box-in-excel-with-a-dynamic-list/ ). As to your last question -- the standard way to return a value from a userform to a calling macro is by putting the value in a public variable which both the userform and the macro have access to.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a userform with a blank ListBox and use this code in the userform module

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ListBox1.AddItem sh.Name
    Next sh
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Sheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an InputBox and have the user select any cell inside the desired/target sheet. Setting the type to 8 returns a Range. From this range, you can get the worksheet then its name.

```
Dim desiredSheetName as String
desiredSheetName = Application.InputBox("Select any cell inside the target sheet: ", "Prompt for selecting target sheet name", Type:=8).Worksheet.Name
Debug.Print desiredSheetName
```