# Excel VBA - Application.CommandBars

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA Script, and I want to exit sub if the user cancels the task.

```vb
Sub Test()    
    'Please note that you need at least 16 worksheets for the following code to work
    
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs").Controls(16).Execute
    
    'I am not sure here what to do to stop the script run after the user cancels the task.

    Msg_Box = msgbox("" & Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs").Controls(16).Execute) 'This is not correct, but just to show what I am after!

    If Msg_Box = "Cancel" Then    
        MsgBox "User Cancelled the Script"
        Exit Sub
    Else
    End If
    
    'Rest of the VBA Script
End Sub
```

Comment: `vbCancel` is a constant with value 2. `vbCancel = True` will never be true.

Comment: You'd need to use something like `If MsgBox("Do you want to cancel?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then` - but reword and use an appropriate button.  When asked this question would you press  OK or Cancel?  Maybe use `vbYesNo) = vbYes` instead.

Comment: @Darren - How do you connect this msgbox to Application.CommandBars?

Comment: I've no idea.  As far as I know you can't capture the click event of that cancel button.  (Invoking the Activate dialog for sheets)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145947/invoking-the-activate-dialog-for-sheets]

Comment: What does `Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs").Controls(16).Execute` do exactly?

Comment: @Tim - This lists down all the worksheets in the workbook and lets the user select one to activate that worksheet (this is similar to right clicking on the arrow keys on the left of the worksheet tabs).

Comment: So the aim is to have the user select a worksheet and then the rest of your script acts on that selected worksheet?   That line has no effect in my Excel though.

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33435959/478884 might be a more robust approach to selecting a worksheet.

Comment: @Tim - Yes, I want the user to select a worksheet and the rest of the script works on this worksheet. As I mentioned in the question, you need at least 16 worksheets for this code to work. And yes your alternative is a good idea instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no simple way to achieve this - monitoring the user input/response from an active commandbar.

MS does provide an option to assign a click event to a commandbar button itself which fires prior to the commandbar button loading. However, in my testing, it appears that the click event only fires when programmatically opening the commandbar button not when manually opening the commandbar button (for example, from the ribbon).

If there is a way to capture the response, there may be a button ID that is not publicly listed by MS for which a click event may be assigned.

Alternatively, monitoring the commandbars.onupdate event may prove useful, with the major drawback being a lack of information regarding the specific updates occurring. But in theory, it may update upon user-input, albeit difficult to detect which button was pressed.

There is also commandbars.getpressedmso which can indicate certain buttons pressed. However, this does not necessarily mean a detection of the recent presses and could simply indicate an option set as active. There may also be a specific msoID not publicly listed by MS which can be used for detection purposes in this case. Extensive testing may be necessary.